# Problem with ifxetex.sty

Tags: xetex, packages, compiling

While compiling(`pdflatex`) with the following code, I am asked to install `ifxetex` package everytime.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={15cm, 5cm}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[5-7]
\end{document}
```

How should I go about it?

`~/tex/latex/ifxetex` has `ifxetex.sty` file in it.

Using `windows Xp`, `MikTeX 2.8` and `WinEdt` IDE

I got the error as shown below when I tried to update the package.

[image]

Comment: We probably need to know which TeX system you use, and which OS. Also, have you run `texhash` on your local tree?

Comment: `texhash` I dunno what it is.

Comment: As you mentioned `~`, I'd assumed you are on *nix (On Windows, you mean `%USERPROFILE%`). MiKTeX needs to be pointed at the local TeX tree, and for you to refresh the file name database. This is done from the MiKTeX Package Manager. Have you done this?

Comment: I don't think the files are residing on `%USERPROFILE% MikTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronize your repository (package manager, menu repository, do it in user + admin mode if you have a multiuser installation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your string ~/tex/latex/ifxetex as a subdirectory below your main user home directory. If this is the case, be sure to tell MikTeX to add the full, rather than the relaive, directory to the list of directories it should search. In the MikTeX Settings program, click on the directories tab, add the directory in question, and then click on Rebuild FMDB in the main tab.